# Using python function within a bash script - to parse JSON

Tags: python, json, bash

I have a bash script that is aimed at parsing the JSON formatted data. I learned from an earlier query on this forum that bash is not good at parsing JSON, and so intend to use a python function to do the parsing:

The following is the code snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

declare -a data_id
declare -a data_tid

function parse_data () {
    python <<EOF
import json
parsed = json.loads('''${@}''')

data_id = []
data_tid = []
for child in parsed['params']['children'][0]:
    print 'id: %s' % (child['data']['id'])
    data_id.append(child['data']['id'])
    print 'tid: %s' % (child['data']['tid'])
    data_tid.append(child['data']['tid'])
EOF
}

json=$(get_json_output)
parse_data $json
```

The data stored in 'json' would look like this:

```
{
    "cid": "1",
    "code": null,
    "error": null,
    "params": {
        "children": [
            {
                "value": {
                    "id": "0123456789",
                    "tid": "a.b.c"
                },
                "data": {
                    "id": "0987654321",
                    "tid": "p.q.r"
                },
                "tid": "m.n.o.p",
            }
        ],
        "tid": "m.n.o.p"
    },
    "reason": null,
    "result": true
}
```

I'd like the script to be able to extract the 'id' and 'tid' fields from under 'data', into separate arrays. But the script execution fails as follows:

```
root@ubuntu# ./abc.sh 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Any idea on what's wrong?

Comment: Try adding quotes while invoking your function: `parse_data "$json"`

Comment: There's a problem with that JSON: the keys 'value', 'data' and 'tid' all appear more than once in the same object. That's not going to work.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: I already corrected a missing comma there; probably a botched copy-paste. I removed the extra keys.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason for not writing the whole script in Python?

Comment: @chepner: The task required that the script be written in bash.

Comment: [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-sed-and-awk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave of the `[0]`:

```
for child in parsed['params']['children']:
```

otherwise you are looping over the keys of the first entry in the `children` list.

Alternatively, if there is only ever *one* entry in that list, don't loop, but directly assign:

```
child = parsed['params']['children'][0]
print 'id: %s' % (child['data']['id'])
port_id.append(child['data']['id'])
print 'tid: %s' % (child['data']['tid'])
port_tid.append(child['data']['tid'])
```

Comment: I observed that the values are not appended to the arrays data_id and data_tid, though the prints work fine. The array size is shown to be zero.

Comment: @Maddy: Are you expecting Python lists to know about your bash arrays? That won't work at all. Subprocesses don't have access to bash variables; you'll have to make the Python process write to stdout or stderr, capture that in your bash script and go from there.

Comment: Is there no way out? Can they not co-exist in the script and share data?

Comment: No, bash is not known for its extensibility. Python is run as a subprocess, it has no access to the memory of the parent process, not without explicit message passing anyway.

Comment: Why not move *everything* to a Python script instead? That'd remove the need to solve that problem at least.

Answer (score 0):

you're referring to only the first item of children list.
so "child" is actually the key of the dictionary.

you should remove the [0] from the FOR loop

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
for child in parsed['params']['children'][0]:
    ...
```

`parsed['params']['children'][0]` is not a list.

change it to either

```
for child in parsed['params']['children']:
    ...
```

or

```
# this one only for testing
for child in [parsed['params']['children'][0]]:
    ...
```

or

```
# also for testing
child = parsed['params']['children'][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You would find this much easier to debug if you *first* wrote the Python script, then tried to embed it in a bash script. Here is the debugged version:

```
import json, sys

parsed = json.load(sys.stdin)

port_id = []
port_tid = []
for child in parsed['params']['children']:
    print 'id: %s' % (child['data']['id'])
    port_id.append(child['data']['id'])
    print 'tid: %s' % (child['data']['tid'])
    port_tid.append(child['data']['tid'])
```

Second, you have a bug in your json data. I think you meant this:

```
{
    "cid": "1",
    "code": null,
    "error": null,
    "params": {
        "children": [
            {
                "value": {
                    "id": "0123456789",
                    "tid": "a.b.c"
                },
                "data": {
                    "id": "0987654321",
                    "tid": "p.q.r"
                },
                "tid": "m.n.o.p"
            },
            {
               "value": {
                    "id": "0987654321",
                    "tid": "a.b.c"
                },
                "data": {
                    "id": "0123456789",
                    "tid": "p.q.r"
                },
                "tid": "m.n.o.p"
            }
        ],
        "tid": "m.n.o.p"
    },
    "reason": null,
    "result": true
}
```

Finally, you still need to load the output into your Bash arrays. Here's my solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

parse_ids() { python -c '
import json, sys
parsed = json.load(sys.stdin)
print u"\n".join(c["data"]["id"] for c in parsed["params"]["children"])'
}

parse_tids() { python -c '
import json, sys
parsed = json.load(sys.stdin)
print u"\n".join(c["data"]["tid"] for c in parsed["params"]["children"])'
}

#json=$(get_json_output)
json=$(</dev/stdin)

declare -a port_id
mapfile -t port_id < <(echo "$json" | parse_ids)
echo "${port_id[@]}"

declare -a port_tid
mapfile -t port_tid < <(echo "$json" | parse_tids)
echo "${port_tid[@]}"
```